# Psycopg2 (curr.execute) Is returning NONE python

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2, psql

I have written a script to update my employee table in psycopg2 but the update is not happening the currr.execute is returning a None object.

my code

```
            connm = psycopg2.connect(database="database", user = "user", password = "pass", host = "localhost", port = "5432")
            connm.autocommit = True
            sql = """ UPDATE employee SET name = %s WHERE phone_number = %s"""
            curr = connm.cursor()
            username = "Mike"
            query = "+0123456789"
            abc = curr.execute(sql, (username, query))
            print abc
            connm.commit()
            curr.close()
```

This abc object is returning None.

Kindly help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect to print?  I think you have more to change if you want a  result than just adding fetch.  Maybe a RETURNING in the update?

Comment: @ChrisTravers I want to check what is returning in my pgadmin Im constantly checking if the update has happened or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting ["Psycopg – PostgreSQL database adapter for Python - execute command"](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#execute):

> The method returns None. If a query was executed, the returned values can be retrieved using fetch*() methods

Then, **None** looks fine. Congrats :)

**Edited** about no effect:

Can you test your query on database?

```
my_raw_query=curr.mogrify(sql, (username, query))
print my_raw_query
```

Check if query is ok and copy paste query on database to check it again.

Comment: The query manually executed  in the pg admin worked the query is .                          " UPDATE employee SET name = 'D****r' WHERE phone_number = '+ 9*****6 (M) '; "       But through psycopg2 its not happening!

Comment: Sure are you working on same database? Please, double check connection string.

Comment: Also, did you try to catch exceptions? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#exceptions

Comment: There are no exceptions or errors simply the update is not happening I have tried eveything!